# Find all those $k$ for which $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots =a_n \pmod k$ where $k\ne1$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

We have a list of numbers represented by $a_1,a_2,... ,a_n$.We have to find all those $k$ for which

$$a_1 = a_2 = \cdots =a_n \pmod k.$$

How do we approach this problem mathematically?

Basically , we need to find all those $k$ for which all the numbers in the list gives same when we do modulus with that $k$.

Comment: Are the numbers integers?  Bear in mind k might be 1.  (Can always be 1.)  I'd think it be a matter of the $\gcd$ of all $a_i - a_k$.  That'd be my first thought.  i.e. a1 = a2 mod k iff k|a1-a2  a2 = a3 mod 3 iff k|a2-a3.  So a1=..... %k iff k|gcd(a1-a2, a1-a3,......).

Comment: @fleablood ,i updated the question .

Comment: I still believe that dxiv has solution.  It's any number that divides the greatest common divisors of the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a_i-a_j \equiv 0 \bmod k$ $\implies k \mid a_i-a_j$ $\implies k \mid \gcd \,\{a_i - a_j \mid 1 \le i \lt j \le n\}$.